# Sesqui-linear forms into C*-algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Are there generalizations of the inner product into $C^*$-algebras? More specifically, I am looking for formulations of $(x,y)\mapsto B(x,y)$ as a nondegenerate sesqui-linear map from $\mathscr{H}\times \mathscr{H} \to \mathscr{C}$ where $\mathscr{H}$ are Hilbert spaces and $\mathscr{C}$ is a $C^*$-algebra. I'm hoping that using such $B(x,y)$, I can similarly define trace class and Hilbert-Schmidt operators.

**Motivation**. In physics and second quantization, we often have operators on the Fock space of the form $\sum_k c^*(A \varphi_k) c(\varphi_k)$ where $\varphi_k$ is an orthonormal basis on the Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$. It's then easy to see that $(\psi,\varphi) \mapsto c^*(\varphi) c(\psi)$ is nondegenerate sesqui-linear. It would then be much easier to manipulate such operators if I knew that such forms satisfy similar properties as the inner product.

Comment: Look for Hilbert modules over C*-algebras.  A nice reference is "Hilbert C*-Modules.  A Toolkit for Operator Algebraists" by E. Christopher Lance

Comment: Wiki article (copy-paste the URL): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_C*-module